# Some AD users do not have user profiles

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, user-profile-service

We have large enterprise system. Some of the AD users do not have user profiles so the code throws a null point exception. When check in user profile list, they do not have user profiles. Why is that? My production access will be removed very soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit the User Profile Service Synchronization Connection to Active Directory.

`Central Admin --> Manage Service Applications --> User Profile Service --> Configure Synchronization Connections --> Select Connection --> Edit`

Then make sure all the required OUs are selected. Thereafter do a full synchronization for the user profile service.